# Efficient "between value" lookup between two Pandas dataframes of different sizes (without using for loop)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes. Dataframe1 has 100 rows and contains the column "Value". Dataframe2 has 1,000 rows and contains the columns "Lower Value" and "Upper Value".

For each row in Dataframe2 I need to find the row in Dataframe1 where "Value" falls between "Lower Value and Upper Value".

I have been doing this with a loop (code below) and this works. However, when I run the code on a very large dataframe (e.g. 1 million rows), then it takes *very* long time to execute.

Is there any way I can do this without a loop that would speed things up?

```
for ind in df2.index:
       v=df2['Value'][ind]
       ID = df1.loc[(v> df1["Lower"]) & (v<= df1["Upper"]),'ID'].values[0]
```

[image: example data]

Comment: Will you please provide a few rows from your two dataframes, and based on that, a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: Did Lower Value and Upper Value overlap between rows on `df2`?

Comment: There is no overlap between Lower and Upper between rows. For example, row 1 would be 0.1 to 0.2 and then row 2 would be 0.2 to 0.3.

Comment: I have added example data to the post

Comment: If row 1 is 0.1-0.2, and row 2 is 0.2-0.3 then there *is* overlap between the rows, specifically at 0.2.... what should happen when a value in df2 lands on one of the thresholds?

Comment: That condition is handled in my code snippet above: >Lower, <= Upper

Answer (score 0):

As your interval does not overlap, you can use `IntervalIndex`:

```
ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['Lower'], df1['Upper'])
df1['Interval'] = ii

out = df2.assign(Interval=pd.cut(df2['Value'], bins=ii)) \
         .merge(df1[['ID', 'Interval']], on='Interval', how='left') \
         .drop(columns='Interval')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Value  ID
0    0.1   1
1    0.2   1
2    0.3   2
3    0.4   2
4    0.5   3
```

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: This has added two columns ID_x and ID_y. All the rows in these columns have the same value.